# Show entered text in jquery autocomplete list

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-autocomplete

I've got a jquery mobile autocomplete form/list. I want to display the entered text, from the input field, as the first option in the list. This works fine, however, this custom list item is not getting styled as the rest of the list items. This is only evident when a single character is pressed. When a second character is entered the style is formatted as it should be.

I'm using the following code to register the keys being pressed:

```
    $('#searchdiv').keyup(function() {
        $('#searchInput a').html($('#searchdiv input').val());

        if($('#searchdiv input').val().length == 0) {
            $('#searchInput').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#searchInput').show();
        }
    });
```

See full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/TAU82/

Is it possible to update the styles when the first character is pressed?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get jQuery mobile to fix it's classes (it adds a `first-child` class to the li element it thinks is first) you need to manually call `$('#contacts').listview('refresh');` for it to refresh

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TAU82/1/)

---

If it's not working on your custom JS I would make sure that the refresh is being called after adding the new node (`<li>`) into the list. The [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html) at the very bottom of the page it talks about how the refresh only affects newly added nodes due to efficiency.
Also they suggest of instead of using `hide()` function to:

> If you initially want to hide a list item you can do this by adding a class of `ui-screen-hidden` to the li element. Using this class ensures the corner styling is applied correctly as well as border-bottom on the last visible item.

Comment: Is it expected that when I move the above code into my custom JS file it doesn't work? However, if I rewrite the function to a normal javascript function, function getInput(), and calls it by onkeyup="getInput()" it works fine?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what the problem is without looking at any code, I've edited my answer to try to help push you in the right direction